# How to extract mm/dd/yyyy from ISO-8601 date format 2014-12-29T22:04:56.000Z in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, iso8601

I have this information: 2014-12-29T22:04:56.000Z

I would like to get the 2014-12-29 part of it in 12/29/2014 format.

How can I do it in javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format the date like this to get your desired formatting.

```js
var date = new Date("2014-12-29T22:04:56.000Z");

function pad(number) {
  if (number < 10) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;
}

function formatDate() {
  return pad(date.getUTCMonth() + 1) +
    '/' + pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '/' + date.getUTCFullYear();
}
console.log(formatDate())
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: There is no need to use a Date, reformatting the string is much more efficient and less problematic.

Comment: @RobG what do you mean by less problematic here? I m open to learn.

Comment: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is largely implementation dependent and really requires a proper parser (there are plenty of good ones). Even parsing of ISO 8601 has some unexpected quirks. So avoiding that (see Quagaar's answer) makes life very much simpler. ;-)

Comment: oh.. I see. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using RegExp replace:

```
var ds = '2014-12-29T22:04:56.000Z';
console.log(ds.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d).+$/, '$2/$3/$1'));
```

Another approach would be using simple String.slice to get the required parts from the date string:

```
console.log(ds.slice(5, 7) + '/' + ds.slice(8, 10) + '/' + ds.slice(0, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

strMDY = strISO.substring(5, 7) + "/" + strISO.substring(8, 10) + "/" + strISO.substring(0, 4)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp